# How to use 'BoldFeatures' to colorize bold texts, but override that color for individual text strings?

Tags: fonts, xetex, color, fontspec, opentype

In my document preamble I use the following code to set my desired font and at the same time to set as default text colors different gray values for italic, bold and bold-italic text:

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
....
\setmainfont[{
   BoldFont=WeidemannStd-Bold.otf,
   ItalicFont=WeidemannBookItalic.otf,
   BoldItalicFont=WeidemannStd-BoldItalic.otf,
   ItalicFeatures={Colour=666666},
   BoldFeatures={Colour=6f6f6f},
   BoldItalicFeatures={Colour=777777}
  }]{WeidemannBook}
```

By and large, this works as expected when generating PDF via *`xelatex`* -- apart from one thing:
if I want to set *specific* bold strings individually to a *different* color, say red, like this:

```
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{these words should be red}}
```

or this:

```
{\textbf{\textcolor{red}these words should be red}}}
```

it does not work as ***I*** expected, and the PDF output for both these strings is still in gray color...

---

***How can I override the gray color which is set as default when using the `fontspec` package's font features?***

Answer (score 3):

A `\addfontfeature` command will overwrite the standard font colours and other features within the specified stretch, e.g.

```
{\addfontfeature{BoldItalicFeatures={Colour=red}}\bfseries\itshape these words are red}
```

But this might not be too practical. A `\newcommand` might work:

```
\newcommand{\mycolouredtext}[2]{{\addfontfeature{%
  ItalicFeatures={Colour=#1},%
  BoldFeatures={Colour=#1},%
  BoldItalicFeatures={Colour=#1}}%
  #2}}
```

Then call `\mycolouredtext{green}{\bfseries\itshape This text is green}` to get a green text that is italicized and boldfaced. This command will not have any influence on other, esp. following, stretches of text.

Btw, there is a syntax error in your last example of code.

```
{\textbf{\textcolor{red}these words should be red}}
```

should be

```
{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{these words should be red}}}
```

otherwise, only the first *t* of *these* will be printed in red.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just started to experiment with the `\addfontfeatures` command too, even before seeing your answer, after coming across it in the fontspec manual. But I didn't get it to work so far. I'll try some more, with your specific suggestions in mind.

Comment: I also corrected the syntax error in my question. It's not in my code, it was just a typo when copying it...

Comment: Currently I don't get it to work in my environment. But the problem may be on my side. The error I encounter is: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ps@plain.`. I'll have to learn + master the `\newcommand` syntax first, before I can debug this further. Thanks for your help.